# How to Convert this code from google android v1 into v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to convert this sample v1 google maps into v2.
I've tried to convert like in tutorial, but I failed, can you help me?

My activity code is like this:

```
package com.mtower.adha.ui;

import greendroid.widget.ActionBar;
import greendroid.widget.ActionBar.Type;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import com.mtower.adha.R;
import com.mtower.adha.db.TowerController;
import com.mtower.adha.models.TowerModel;
import com.mtower.adha.utilities.MapOverlay;


public class Map extends MapActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private MapController mapController;
    private GeoPoint gpUser, p;
    private SharedPreferences prefLocation;

    private Context mContext;
    String lat, lon, name, alamat;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        mContext = this;

        actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.myActionBar);
        actionBar.setTitle("Cellular Tower Maps");
        actionBar.setType(Type.Empty);
        actionBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        actionBar.getHandler();


        initMap();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void initMap() {
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();
        LinearLayout myzoom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoom);
        myzoom.addView(zoomView);
        mapView.setStreetView(false);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
        // Untuk mengambil lokasi user saat ini
        prefLocation = mContext.getSharedPreferences("mkul", 0);
        double latUser = Double.parseDouble(prefLocation.getString("userLat",
                "0"));
        double lonUser = Double.parseDouble(prefLocation.getString("userLon",
                "0"));
        gpUser = new GeoPoint((int) (latUser * 1E6), (int) (lonUser * 1E6));

        mapController = mapView.getController();

        TowerController rc = new TowerController(mContext);
        List<TowerModel> lsRm = rc.getAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < lsRm.size(); i++) {
            TowerModel poi = lsRm.get(i);

            lat = poi.getLat();
            lon = poi.getLon();
            name = poi.getName();
            alamat = poi.getAddress();

            String coordinates[] = {lat, lon};

            double lati = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
            double longi = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

            p = new GeoPoint((int) (lati * 1E6), (int) (longi * 1E6));

            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            int draw = R.drawable.marker;
            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(draw);
            MapOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MapOverlay(drawable,mContext,poi);
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, name, alamat);
            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
        }
        mapController.animateTo(gpUser);
        mapController.setZoom(16); 
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Which code must be changed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This isn't a site where you just post a lot of code and ask us to fix it for you or rewrite it for something. If you have a clear, specific problem, you need to describe it, and ask a specific question about it. "Fix this code for me" or "what do I change?" is not specific at all. What **exactly** is the problem you're having with the code? Where **specifically** is the problem code located?

Comment: sepurane bar jumatan..

@KenWhite:
okay,i'm sorry about that,
i just run that code into my device, but that code for android maps v1,i don't have apikey v1,so i must change it into v2, my question is where line of code must be i change?
sorry if my english so bad,i can't talk english well, ^_^